# How to convert executable jar to text file.?

Tags: mobile, executable-jar

I have a executable jar file and i want to see code behind it.  
 
Is this possible?

- If yes then tell me the way.
- If no then tell me what can i do?

---

I have download this jar from <[**http://www.4shared.com/file/FKZjrzCu/FB_Chat.html**](http://www.4shared.com/file/FKZjrzCu/FB_Chat.html)>  
Thank you.

Comment: You have to register to dowload this file. Doesn't look very trustworthy though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download Java decompiler from http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui
2. Open the executable jar file using winrar or winzip.
3. Place the .class files into Java decompiler application to view the code.

Comment: Thank you so much.
But i don't have a class file.
I already have a software which can convert class file to text..
But i don have a class file..
Please help me..

Comment: .class files are inside the .jar file (archive file). Sometimes, there are .jar files inside other .jar files, so you could have to do the extract again.

Comment: The link is no more available. Do you have another java decompiler that can take multiple class file then merge the code (online if it's possible) ?